# Airflow add a UI button for each DAG

Tags: airflow

By default each DAG has a bunch of buttons (`Trigger Dag`, `Delete Dag` etc) in the main (Admin) view in the UI.
I have been trying to add a buttonlike the ones described above that every time you click it it send an Http request.

I have successfully used these plugin:
https://github.com/airflow-plugins/Getting-Started/blob/master/Tutorial/creating-ui-modification.md

But it does not do what I need and digging around airflow code and the docs for plugins didnt help much either, is it possible to do what Im trying to do? How?

Comment: Refer to [`discreETL`](https://github.com/Wikia/discreETLy) and [QDS Button](https://dzone.com/articles/the-fun-of-creating-apache-airflow-as-a-service) for hints