# How to modify styling of page views in airflow?

Tags: python, airflow

I was hoping to change the icons and text being used in the navigation bar in apache airflow. When I do inspect element, I get that [`pin_100.png`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/master/airflow/www/static) is being used. I was hoping to change this to a custom image and title. Where do I edit files for this? I am guessing this has something to do with flask views (?) but I'm not certain.

I see from [here](https://flynn.gg/blog/airflow-flask-plugins/) that the flask template base view should be modified (?). I still can't figure out how.

I would like to change the "Airflow" text, and the icon, to my custom text and icon.

EDIT: For more clarity, I just found this. This is what I want to modify

```
<img style="float: left; width:35px; margin-top: -7px;"
                   src="{{ url_for("static", filename="pin_100.png") }}"
                   title="{{ current_user.username }}">
              <span>
                Airflow
              </span>
```

I want to change the filename and **Airflow**

It resides in https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/www/templates/appbuilder/navbar.html

Comment: Hi; see if you can get some hints from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54402793/3679900)

Comment: @y2k-shubham I'm not sure if I understand correctly. It says to add menu buttons. I want to edit the icon and text. Not sure if that link helps.

Comment: I meant [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54402793/airflow-add-a-ui-button-for-each-dag#comment95639133_54402793)